# OSGi environment: MOXy as JSON provider gives MarshalException

Tags: json, osgi, jax-rs, eclipselink, moxy

Environment: OSGi via Equinox with Jersey and MOXy

I have a simple class as ReST component:

```
package test.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import test.domainobjects.TestDomainObject;

@Path( "/test" )
public class TestTheRest {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    //@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Object getTestEntity() {
        return new TestDomainObject();
    }
}
```

and a simple entity

```
package test.domainobjects;
public class TestDomainObject {    
    public int fieldA = 1;
    public String fieldB = "Some content";
}
```

When I start my launch configuration and run a GET on `<server>:<port>/services/test`, I get a 500 error and an exception which I can only see in the debugger:

> javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
>    - with linked exception:
>   [Exception [EclipseLink-25003] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
>   Exception Description: An error occurred marshalling the object
>   Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-25007] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
>   Exception Description: A descriptor for class test.domainobjects.TestDomainObject was not found in the project.  For JAXB, if the JAXBContext was bootstrapped using TypeMappingInfo[] you must call a marshal method that accepts TypeMappingInfo as an input parameter.]

The thing is that I am using the [OSGi - JAX-RS Connector](https://github.com/hstaudacher/osgi-jax-rs-connector) (with [MOXy provider](https://github.com/hstaudacher/osgi-jax-rs-connector/tree/master/bundles/com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.provider.moxy)), so all the wiring happens under the hood.

How am I supposed to supply a *descriptor*? And why? Shouldn't MOXy be able to convert a POJO to JSON without additional details?

Comment: Try adding `@XmlRootElement` on top of the model class.

Comment: Same exception (I remember that I tried that before)

Comment: It sounds VERY fishy that you get an XML Marshalling exception while you request JSON. Unless the JSON translation goes through XML (would be horribly inefficient), you're seeing something else than you think you're seeing.

Comment: I agree. However, I have extracted a stack trace and [posted it at PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/KHBZh8vT); it definitely stems from `MOXyJsonProvider`.